# Defining Macro in C for MIN of 2 numbers

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

`#define MIN (A,B) ((A)<(B)?(A):(B))` OR `#define MIN (A,B) ((A < B)? A : B )`

Please Choose one answer and why ?!

Comment: please use neither. macros that evaluate arguments more than once are just dangerous. Modern C has type generic expressions that can help to to chose the right inline function for the job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's have this expression:

```
int c = MIN(x == y, 1);
```

Let's try the `#define MIN (A,B) ((A < B) ? A : B )`

In C the `==` operator has lesser precedence to `<` (so `x == y < z` is equivalent to `x == (y < z)`), so it will become

```
int c = MIN (x == (y < 1) ? x == y : 1)
```

if you use the second expression... And it's wrong, so it's better the first form.

Let's try the `#define MIN (A,B) ((A) < (B) ? (A) : (B))` just to be sure...

here we have

```
int c = MIN ((x == y) < (1) ? (x == y) : (1))
```

much better!

In the end they are both "bad", because

```
int c = MIN(++x, 1);
```

will have the `++x` evaluated twice (once in the `<` comparison and once if it's "selected" by the ternary operator as the result)

```
int c = MIN ((++x) < (1) ? (++x) : (1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I wouldn't use either, since expressions like `MIN(++a, ++b)` can screw you over (due to double evaluation).

Comment: Can you elaborate why this is an issue.

Comment: It is undefined behavior like `a++ < b++` is undefined behavior.

Comment: a++ < b++ is well defined, but the macro would increase the min of a and b twice: `++a < ++b ? ++a : ++b`

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt and @Eric Postpischil you are right I was confused with this type of an expression `a++ < ++a`, which does eventually happen.

Comment: @EricPostpischil N1570 6.5.15p4 states "The first operand is evaluated; there is a **sequence point** between its evaluation and the
evaluation of the second or third operand (whichever is evaluated)." (emphasis mine). `++a < ++b ? ++a : ++b` is well-defined.

Answer (score 2):

My personal preference would be:

```
inline int min(int a, int b) 
{
   return (a > b)?b:a;
}
```

This is much safer, doesn't require extra parenthesis, and doesn't "blow up" if you do something like :

```
x = min(x++, y++);
```

Comment: Practically, would anyone ever use min(x++, y++)?  It seems like a really bad coding decision even if the routine worked properly.

Comment: Yes, but you may want to do `while(*ptr) lowest = min(*ptr++, lowest);` or something like that - which will also behave strangely if it's a macro.

Answer (score 0):

The former, as A or B could be nested commands. Consider how the two macros would expand this:

```
int i = MIN(3+1,2);
```

Comment: The former indeed fixes the nesting problem, but will still mess up due to double evaluation. Consider the expansion of `int i = MIN(6, a++)` for `int a = 10`.